# How to tar all files with wildcard character (*) using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, wildcard

This is the command I want to run under python. Basically I want to `tar` all files under a folder:

```
tar -jcvf doo.tar.gz /home/user/doo/*
```

---

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz', '/home/user/doo/*'])
```

That returns following error:

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/user/doo/*: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

---

Later I tried it using `glob`.

```
import subprocess,  glob
subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz', glob.glob("*")])
```

That returns following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dd.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz', glob.glob("*")])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1490, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

---

Following approach works but I am not sure how to provide all file names as one after another:

```
import subprocess,  glob
subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz', 'hello.txt', 'world.txt'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz', glob.glob("*")])
```

`glob` returns a list of strings. You shouldn't embed that inside the list passed to `run`, but instead append it.

```
subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz'] + glob.glob("*"))
```

Note that you've ommitted the home directory.

```
subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz'] + glob.glob("/home/user/doo/*"))
```

Comment: Could I also do it as: `res = subprocess.check_output(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz'] + glob.glob("*")).decode('utf-8')` in order to obtain the output? @John Kugelman

Answer (score 1):

Shell is the one that can expand `*`. So specify `shell=True` in your subprocess call to expand it.

```
subprocess.run(['tar', '-jcvf', 'doo.tar.gz', '/home/user/doo/*'], shell=True)
```