# Error with subprocess Popen and shell=False for the tar command

Tags: python

I have following simple python code that aims to minic
`/usr/bin/tar -czvf x002.tgz *.py`

The code is:

```
import subprocess

base_dir = "/home/workspace/x002"
tar_file = "x002.tgz"
py_file = "*.py"
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/tar", "-czvf", tar_file, py_file], cwd=base_dir, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     shell=False)
results = []
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline().decode('utf8').strip()
    if line == '' and p.poll() is not None:
        break
    else:
        results.append(line)

print(results)
```

I confirm that there exists `py` files under the directory of `base_dir`, but it complains as follows, I don't know where the problem is ,could someone help take a look? Thanks!

```
['tar: *.py: Cannot stat: No such file or directory', 'tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tar all files with wildcard character (\*) using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245068/how-to-tar-all-files-with-wildcard-character-using-subprocess)

Comment: Yes, thanks @Nishant for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code will reproduce the issue you are facing:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ls", "*"],
    shell=False
)
```

The problem is that wildcard `*` expansion is a *shell* (`bash`, `zsh` etc.) feature; commands like `tar`, `ls` etc. don't understand it. It is evaluated by the shell *prior* to the command execution (using `exec` system call). You can fix this by supplying `shell=True`. It will cause Python to use a shell to execute the command. Read more about it here: [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).

However, it is better to use `shell=False` in Python scripts since that avoids spawning an extra shell. Python has an equivalent feature called [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) that does the same thing. This will change the coding style a bit i.e. instead of thinking about executing commands in an interactive shell from Python, you think about doing the same thing using Python's features like variable, functions etc.

Comment: Thanks @Nishant for the great help!